# Can't get past BIOS after Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Server Install

Tags: boot

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS server on a 3TB HDD using a USB. The install appears to go fine but when it finishes and I restart the computer, it goes straight to the ASUS BIOS. I've disabled secure boot and played around with the CSM settings but nothing will let me get past the BIOS. I plugged in the old 1TB HDD with windows 10 on it and it boots no problem. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by updating the BIOS.